# Totales en Matriz de Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Tengo la siguiente visualización que cree con Power BI y una matriz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto lo logre poniendo los siguientes parametros:

- En Filas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- En Columnas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- En valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, necesito los totales de cada una de las columnas por año, algo como lo que tengo en la siguiente imagen, pero en una sola matriz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de como se podría construir?

De la data no se preocupen que de infinito o algo por el estilo, pues es Data Dummy

¡Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues simplemente crea otra tabla pero no añadas el campo de 'Linea Waste' en las columnas.

Ahora si lo necesitas en la misma tabla, las matrices tienen una opción de configurar subtotales de columnas, pero debes primero intercambiar el orden de 'Linea Waste' y Date[Año] para que te muestre solamente dos subtotales: 2021 y 2022.